# Binance API how to get price ticker with specific date time

Tags: datetime, binance, price

How to fetch with specific date or date time? I have searched with `api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr?symbol=BTCUSDT` but I want to fetch with etc. `api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/1274123617?symbol=BTCUSDT` in this URL after ticker the number is Unix date time (2022-05-17 19:13:37), but unfortunately I can't get response.

Answer (score 0):

This ticket endpoint can only retrieve the last ticker information. You may interest in getting histrocial kline data by: `GET /api/v3/klines`

Also from https://data.binance.vision/ you could download the archived historical data in zip files.